# What is the difference between casting long.MaxValue to int and casting float.MaxValue to int?

Tags: c#, types, casting

I'm trying to understand difference between some data types and conversion.

```
public static void ExplicitTypeConversion2()
    {
        long longValue=long.MaxValue;
        float floatValue = float.MaxValue;
        int integerValue = (int) longValue;
        int integerValue2 = (int)floatValue;
        Console.WriteLine(integerValue);
        Console.WriteLine(integerValue2);            
    }
```

When I run that code block, it outputs:

```
-1
-2147483648
```

I know that if the value you want to assign to an integer is bigger than that integer can keep, it returns the minimum value of integer (-2147483648).

As far as I know, `long.MaxValue` is much bigger than the maximum value of an integer, but if I cast `long.MaxValue` to `int`, it returns -1.

What is the difference these two casting? I think the first one also suppose to return -2147483648 instead of -1.

Comment: I'm wondering the other way round.... `int i = (int)long.MaxValue` fills `i` with `0xFFFFFFFF` which is `-1`, so that is clear to me. I wonder why `int i = (int)float.MaxValue` ends up in `int.MinValue` which is `0x80000000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain:

```
long longValue=long.MaxValue;
float floatValue = float.MaxValue;
int integerValue = (int) longValue;
int integerValue2 = (int)floatValue;
```

The maximum value of long is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 or 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, thus 2's complement after reducing it into 0xFFFFFFFF will return 0x00000001 with minus sign bit, represented as -1 in decimal.

On the other side, the maximum value of float is 3.40282347E+38, thus casting it to int rounded the value to 3E+38 and using 2's complement after reducing it we get the hex value of 0x80000000 with minus sign bit, there is -2147483648 in decimal.

All of this case applies on signed integers, the result will be different on unsigned ones.

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You argument regarding the conversion from float to int is incorrect.Your statement "3.40282347E+38, thus casting it to int rounded the value to 3E+38" is correct only on paper and pen, not in a computer

Comment: it all amounts to the internal representation... The trunking of 64 bit Long.Maxvalue to 32 bit int in hexadecimal is **0xFFFFFFFF** which is by -1 in the signed integer representation on 2's complement. The float.maxvalue represented bitwise as **0x7FFFFFFF** is in turn bitwise equal to Integer.maxvalue on two's complement representation.

Comment: @JoãoRebelo the float that has the bit pattern 0x7FFFFFFF is a NaN, and the internal representation doesn't really matter for a float->int cast

Comment: I can't understand why this answer was tagged as accepted! It is not accurate nor clear. I think @harlod 's answer, voted 13 till now, should be tagged as accepted, not this ...

Comment: From 3rd remark in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx: `When you convert from a double or float value to an integral type, the value is truncated [i.e. to nearest possible value]. If the resulting integral value is outside the range of the destination value, the result depends on the overflow checking context.` That's why explicit numeric cast silently perform conversion from Single.MinValue into Int32.MinValue without throwing `OverflowException`.

Comment: @harold, ok... didn't know that! thanks for the clarification

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto How 3E+38 is reduced to 0x80000000?

Comment: @AhmadWabbi By truncating into significant 8 bits eligible for integer conversion. To prove truncation process similarly, open a calculator in programmer mode and insert 3E+18 in decimal (since 3E+38 is too large, calculator can only show 19 significant digits) with Qword value, converting it to hex gives 0x29A2241AF62C0000. Change in Dword value and returning 0xF62C0000, then set back to decimal and get -164888576 (from my experience btw).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto You can never get 0x80000000 from 3E+38 this way.  Using this calculator: https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm, the hex value representing 3E+38 is `e1b1 e5f9 0f94 4d6e 1c9e 66c0 0000 0000`. Where is  0x80000000 ?

Answer (score 16):

> if the value you want to assign to an integer, bigger than that integer can keep, returns minimum value of integer

That's not a rule. The relevant rules are

For integer types in an `unchecked` context (ie the default):

> If the source type is larger than the destination type, then the source value is truncated by
>   discarding its “extra” most significant bits. The result is then treated as a value of the destination
>      type.

For float->int in an `unchecked` context:

> The value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within
>   the range of the destination type, then this value is the result of the conversion.
>   Otherwise, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.

Chopping off 32 leading bits of off `0x7fffffffffffffff` gives `0xffffffff` aka -1.

You were never promised you would get `int.MinValue` for that out of range float->int cast, but you do anyway because it's easy to implement: x64's conversion instruction [cvtss2si](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSS2SI.html) makes 0x80000000 for out of range results and similarly [fistp](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FIST:FISTP.html) (the old x87 conversion instruction used by the 32bit JIT) stores "the integer indefinite value" which is 0x80000000.

Comment: in C# casting works based on Hexadecimal format ? 0x7fffffffffffffff or binary behind the scenes? I mean for example converting from a type to another, if I convert the value of it to binary to check other types number of bits, so decide to whether i can keep or loss data

Comment: @Tuncaf there is no format behind the scenes. Hexadecimal and binary are just two equally good ways to visualize what's going on (but hex is shorter, that's the only reason I chose it).

Answer (score 6):

The binary value of `long.MaxValue` is `0111...111111`(a zero followed by 63 ones). When you cast to `int`, you keep the lowest 32 bits `111...11111`. This is `-1` in decimal, as `int` is `signed` and two's complement applies.

Comment: In decimal it should be "4294967295" but because Int32 has a max value of 2147483647 when this nubmer is reached it starts counting from - 2147483648 (its min value) and then indeed reaches -1.

Comment: @PaulWeiland No. If `unsigned`, the value would be `4294967295`. But as `int` is `signed`, a sequence of 32 ones equals `-1` in two's complement.