# Casting long.MaxValue -> float -> long results in overflown value

Tags: c#, floating-point, long-integer

We noticed quite a problem in our codebase lately which caused our RNG to go bonkers. Currently all our game variables are saved as floats, among them the max long value from the game server. When this is parsed by the client, its converts the float back into a long. So far okay we thought, as the float simply gets truncated. However, on close inspection its actually not the case. For unknown reasons the long overflows to a negative value of -9223372036854775808.

Why is that? Why an overflow?

Here's a simple C# example to reproduce:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    float test = long.MaxValue;
    long testLong = (long) test;
    Console.WriteLine("[random debug]: " + test + " vs. " +testLong);
}
```

which will print:

```
[random debug]: 9.223372E+18 vs. -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: nearly the same question, here you go:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853535/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-long-maxvalue-to-int-and-casting-float-ma/37853724

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit-numeric-conversions-table, especially the remarks section about converting a double/float to an integral type. Now, what you could do is checking (or clamping) the float value before converting it to a long like this for example: `long myLong = (myFloat >= long.MaxValue) ? long.MaxValue : (long) myFloat;`

Comment: @user1519979 I see, thank you! Apologies for not searching enough and opening a new question.

Comment: Just adding to @elgonzo's comment above, you could also perform a checked casting operation by writing `long testLong = checked((long) test);`. Checked castings will throw an `OverflowException` whenever the casting cannot be done due to values on the original data type (`float`, in your case) being outside of the supported range of values for the target type (`long`, in your case).

Comment: The *float* type does not have nearly enough precision to be able to store all digits in long.MaxValue.  It can't store more than 7, long.MaxValue requires 19.  So the value gets rounded to a value that float *can* store, it happened to get rounded up.  To a value that *long* can no longer represent and causing overflow.  Overflowing long.MaxValue turns on the sign bit, producing a value close to long.MinValue.  Or to put it another way, you can't store 8 bytes in a value that takes 4 byte of storage and expect the get the same result.